# Select N locations from a list to maximize the total profit from neighborhoods of the selected locations

Tags: algorithm

Out of 1000 locations, 250 locations are eligible for setting up an outlet. I want select 5 localities of these 250 such that it maximizes the sum of profits from neighborhoods of selected locations and the outlets are at least 5 miles apart. Willingness of people to travel from one location to another is given (which defines neighborhood of that location)

I have tried integer programming but had problems in defining the objective function. Any clustering/optimization technique that can solve this problem?

EDIT:

Given:

- 1000 locations and great circle distance between any two locations
- Willingness of people to travel from one location to another for all 1000 locations
- 250 eligible locations

Objective:

To maximize the profit from 5 clusters where each cluster contains a selected location and all locations from where people are willing to travel to the selected location.

Constraints:

- Total selected locations have to be 5 and have to be from 250 eligible locations
- Selected locations have to be at least 5 miles apart
- Every location can belong to only one cluster

Comment: Maybe you will get a better response on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are the profits of one outlet independant of the locations of the other outlets? Example: location `A` has an outlet, location `B` does not. Could the profits at `A` change if I decide to open an outlet at `B`?

Comment: @Carsten Yes, if there is location C that belongs to neighborhoods of both A and B. Profits of C can be counted only in either A or B. So opening outlet at B can affect profits of A.

Comment: [You shouldn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) [cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/199139/select-n-locations-from-a-list-to-maximize-the-total-profit-from-neighborhoods-o).

Comment: @Dukeling I honestly didn't know. Deleted the other one.

Comment: What about using a tool like METIS (http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/views/metis) to partition the 1000 locations in 5 partitions of similar aggregated purchase power and then select the 5 outlet locations to be near the centers of the partitions?

Comment: @AxelKemper does it guarantee profit maximization? Also, the neighborhood cluster can contain only localities with willingness to travel.

Comment: "where each cluster contains a selected location and all locations from where people are willing to travel to the selected location."  So if even 1 person is willing to travel to both New York and Philadelphia, then you can't have outlets at both locations?

Comment: @mbeckish you can have outlets at both locations but the profit can be counted only under one cluster i.e. you can't double count the profits

Answer (score 2):

a constrained full enumeration shouldl do for this problem size:

1. enumerate all feasible locations combinations not violating the "at least 5 miles apart" constraint. A simple recursion, easily parallelized.
2. for each of combinations from #1 calculate the total number of locations "covered" by the layout and pick the max. For each node in these 1000 find which outlet if any people from the node will go and +1 if any outlet is reachable. Easily parallelized, again.
3. Optional. Out of those equally good prefer the ones with the best "load balancing".

The problem you are working on is:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem

Classic heuristics of approaching these are branch&bound, genetic, annealing. The full enumeration would be used to validate that heuristic is able to approach the global minimum efficiently on small problem sizes.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, is this what you meant?
* Of 250c5 combinations filter the ones with distance greater than 5 miles
* For each 5 outlets combination, find sum of profits from all the locations willing to travel to these 5 outlets and maximum is the solution.
- Excellent brute force method. But, I want the algorithm to work for say 25 outlets selection then this method would be very expensive

Comment: @san8055 - yeah, It doesn't scale, but it will let you get a better feeling of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want the following:

let variable `Li` represent location `i` being selected or not. (i = 1..250)

Let `Si = {Lj for all j such that distance(Li, Lj) <= 5 miles}`

Let `Ci` be a constant representing the value of neighborhood of `Li`

The constraints are:

```
Sum Si <= 1
Li = 1 or 0
Sum(Li for all i) == 5
```

the Objective function is
maximize `Sum(Li*Ci for all i)`

Comment: Objective function is not correct as value of the neighborhood is not a constant that can be calculated before hand. Locations that are part of neighborhood of a location are dependent on which other locations have an outlet.

Comment: @san8055 You haven't defined one properly!

Comment: @ElKamina Edited the question to add more clarity